# Permission denied when trying to run systrace

Tags: android, terminal, systrace

I'm trying to run the new systrace tool provided by the Android SDK.  As demoed during Google I/O 2012 ([Demo starts at 31:04 in the video](http://youtu.be/Q8m9sHdyXnE?t=31m4s)) ([Terminal commands demoed at 32:04](http://youtu.be/Q8m9sHdyXnE?t=32m4s)). .

However, when I try to run the command (in Terminal on a Mac) I get the following:

```
-bash: ./systrace.py: Permission denied
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out by learning more about UNIX permissions. The systrace.py file had its permissions set to: `-rw-r--r--` so I wasn't allowed to execute it. I used chmod to change the permissions to allow me to execute it and now I can run it.

Also: in case it helps someone... trace.html does not open in Firefox, try using Chrome.

Comment: How's are your permissions: 755?